# Straight Line when representing Lowpass filter in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, lowpass-filter, hamming-window

I try to implement an Lowpass filter using a Hammond Window. The cut-off frequency it's 0.3 and the order of the filter it's 21. My problem is that I have a straight line and it's not crossing through the represented points. Here it's the code:

```
from pylab import *
import scipy.signal as signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#Plot step and impulse response
def impz(b,a=1):
    l = len(b)
    impulse = repeat(0.,l); impulse[0] =1.
    x = arange(0,l)
    response = signal.lfilter(b,a,impulse)
    subplot(211)
    stem(x, response)
    ylabel('Amplitude')
    xlabel(r'Index')
    title(r'Impulse response')
   
n = 21
a = signal.firwin(n, cutoff = 0.3, window = "hamming")
#Impulse and step response
figure(2)
impz(a)
show()
```

I've attached you how should the pyplot look like: [image: correct plot]

And here it's my plot: [image: my wrong plot]

Why it's the red line in the last picture not crossing through the points of the plot? Any ideas why? Thanks!

Comment: thanks, it worked :) any tips about how can I improve my code? Can you answer so I can mark your code as solved? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`plt.stem`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stem.html) [draws](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/stem_plot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-stem-plot-py) dots with vertical lines connected via a baseline, as shown in your second plot. To draw dots and connected line segments, there is [`plt.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) with many options.

Note that usually `pyplot` is imported as `plt`. That way, people can quickly see where the plotting related code is happening, which makes it easier to understand and maintain.

Similarly, `numpy` is imported as `np`. Numpy functions can work on complete arrays similar to working with single variables (["broadcasting"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)), which only works fine when all functions and arrays use numpy. The prefix `np` helps in visually checking this.

Here is the sample code with the standard way of importing pyplot and numpy. And with a call to `plt.plot` to obtain a plot similar to the desired one. The variable in the main code is renamed to `b` to make the call to the `impz` function easier to follow.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as signal

# Plot step and impulse response
def impz(b, a=1):
    l = len(b)
    impulse = np.repeat(0., l)
    impulse[0] = 1.
    x = np.arange(0, l)
    response = signal.lfilter(b, a, impulse)
    plt.subplot(211)
    # plt.stem(x, response)
    plt.plot(x, response, color='blueviolet', marker='o', markerfacecolor='none', markeredgecolor='dodgerblue')
    plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
    plt.xlabel('Index')
    plt.title('Impulse response')

n = 21
b = signal.firwin(n, cutoff=0.3, window="hamming")
# Impulse and step response
plt.figure(2)
impz(b)
plt.show()
```

[image: sample plot]